# createDirectoryAtPath not working - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ipad, xcode4

I am trying to create a new directory, and it should be way easier than this. I've looked at numerous tutorials, and am virtually copy and pasting the code, but I'm getting an error "use of undeclared identifier createDirectoryAtPath" each time. Here is my code:

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;
NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *docsDir;
NSString *newDir;

filemgr =[NSFileManager defaultManager];

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
    NSUserDomainMask, YES);

docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
newDir = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"pdf"];

if ([createDirectoryAtPath:newDir withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error: NULL] == NO)
{
        // Failed to create directory
}
[filemgr release];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I should mention I have this code in the .m file, within -(void)viewDidLoad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call createDirectoryAtPath: on the filemanager

```
if ([filemgr createDirectoryAtPath:newDir withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error: NULL] == NO)
```

Comment: That appears to work. For some reason, files I write to that directory aren't showing up, but that's a separate issue. Thanks a bunch. I will mark it correct as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to include the object that you want to send the message to.  As joern said, you need to send the createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes message to the NSFileManager instance, filemgr.

Comment: Yes, that did work. I don't know why the other code examples did not have this part. Shame that because of that, I had to have a question voted down.